# SQL Server 2016 Shrink During Migration

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F09K.png)We have DWH server working on SQL Server 2016 which we planning to move another server.
But we have some databases which is about 2T but this databases in real size about 400G i mean if i will shrink these database they will be about 400G.
As you know DWH servers always has a drop and create objects.

I am searching about shrink when backup and restore to new server but i don't see for Ms SQL SERVER. Is there any way to migrate to new server with real size databases ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Shrink The Database Before Taking Backup.

```
DECLARE @string     NVARCHAR(4000), 
        @Strt       INT ,
        @END        INT ,
        @DBName     NVARCHAR(255),
        @Log_Size   DECIMAL(18,5),
        @Log_Name   NVARCHAR(25),
        @String_sql NVARCHAR(MAX)

CREATE TABLE #t (srno INT IDENTITY(1,1),filename NVARCHAR(255),DBNAME NVARCHAR(50))  
CREATE TABLE #Tmp_logfile (fileName NVARCHAR(25),file_size DECIMAL(12,5),log_Name NVARCHAR(25))

--  file_id =2 Log File & file_id =1 MDf File NAme
    INSERT INTO #Tmp_logfile (fileName,file_size,log_Name)
    SELECT a.NAME , CONVERT(DECIMAL(12,5),ROUND(b.size/128.000,5)),b.name 
    FROM SYS.DATABASES  a 
    INNER JOIN  SYS.MASTER_FILES b ON a.database_id=b.database_id
    WHERE a.database_id > 4 AND b.file_id =2 


    INSERT INTO #t
    SELECT 
            'USE [' + d.name + N']' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
            + 'DBCC SHRINKFILE (N''' + mf.name + N''' , 20)'  
            + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) as fileName,d.name
            FROM 
            sys.master_files mf 
            JOIN sys.databases d 
            ON mf.database_id = d.database_id 
            WHERE d.database_id > 4 AND mf.file_id=2;



      SET @Strt=1
      SELECT @END= Max(Srno)FROM #t

      EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
                IF ''?'' not in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')
                begin
                    exec (''ALTER DATABASE [?] SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;'')
                    print ''?''
                end'


      While @Strt<=@END
        BEGIN

            SELECT  @string= FileName,@DBName= DBNAME FROM #t WHERE srno= @Strt
            SELECT  @Log_Size= file_size FROM #Tmp_logfile WHERE fileName=  @DBName

            IF @Log_Size > 5000 BEGIN   -- Limit The Log Size After which Log file to be Shrink for EG I Had Select 5 GB

                    PRINT (@string)
                    EXECUTE (@string)
            END
            SET @Strt=@Strt+1

        END       ---- SHRINKING Log File END Here

        EXEC sp_msforeachdb '
                IF ''?'' not in (''master'',''model'',''msdb'',''tempdb'')
                begin
                    exec (''ALTER DATABASE [?] SET RECOVERY FULL;'')
                    print ''?''
                end'

DROP TABLE #t
DROP TABLE #Tmp_logfile
```

Comment: But manual shrink will get too long time. I need something different. Is there any option to get shrinked database backup ? Or shrinked restore ? I cant shrink manually it takes much time. I tried before 3 days passed it was only 50% processed.

Comment: What's The Current log Size of your Database

Comment: you Have to Make Backup file to ZIP Or Rar FIle.

Comment: database is simple mode, log size is about 25G. I am talking about of datafiles. If we shrink datafile we will get 600G. I want to get back this allocated empty size.

Comment: zip or rar can be both, doesnt matter.

Comment: what's Your INtial_siz(MB)Can you Check it in File

Comment: Initial size is 1.063.625 and also i added picture in post. If i shrink how much space i will earn in picture.

Comment: Not This One this of Shrinking the Database FILE. wan't I want to KNow IS INtial_siz(MB).you will get This IN DB_NAME >>Properties>>File >>INtial_siz(MB)

Comment: Yes i understood but my initial size 1.063.625 in dbname>>properties>>file>>initial size.

Comment: Try This for Shrinking the MDF_File

SELECT * FROM Sys.databases   
SELECT * FROM SYS.master_files WHERE file_id=1

USE [Test]
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'MDF File Name' , 404805)

Comment: what is doing this query ?

Comment: will shrink Data file your file NOTE Before Shrinking you should Take Backup Of DB to Avoid Any Issue occur

Comment: yes as i understood its not any way when taking backup shrink file automatically right ? thanks for script and help Ahmed

Comment: @GeorgeWidgi There Is a Way IF you Go Through the Script You will Definitely find it.make sure When ever you run Backup Script just before it run shrink file .It will solve your problem Thanks